# Pandas Merge - CSV Column data is offset/misaligned

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a merged two dataframes where the values are not starting from the top row when looking at the CSV file created.

```
import pandas as pd

df_ifOperStatus = pd.read_csv('WG_ifOperStatus.csv')
df_IfDescr = pd.read_csv('TEST_ifDescr.csv')

merge = df_IfDescr.merge(df_ifOperStatus, left_on='Desc', right_on='if', how='left')
merge.to_csv('MergeTEST.csv', index=False)
```

When viewing the combined dataset the column data is not together. The merge combined two CSV with two columns each, giving more four columns in the merged file.

Instead i get four columns where dataset two begins on row 100 for example.

```
Desc         ONT            if  ifOperStatus 
17972705281  ADTN2019402e       
17972715521  ADTN2000604b       
17972725761  ADTN201942fc       
17972736001  ADTN20124a09       
17972746241  ADTN20002d95       
17972756481  ADTN2100a0b6       
                            1   up
                            2   down
                            3   down
                            4   down
                            5   down
                            6   down
```

I added axis=1 when using concat and it fixed the issue, but I need merge for this use case.

I also need Column 1 and 3 to match to and filter out anything in 3 that is not in 1. But that may be another post.

I'm sure I've missed something simple but this is new to me and I haven't found a post or YouTube video describing this issue yet.

Comment: `pd.concat` align by the indices of the two frames. Your `merge` aligns `Desc` with `If` for which there is no match, hence the extra rows. Try `df_IfDescr.merge(df_ifOperStatus, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')`

Comment: This works and brings all data to the top of the table, but how do I filter column "if" to show match the values in "Desc"? Eventually the "if" values begin to match "Desc" after about 100 rows. @CodeDifferent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my approach, so this specific issue is no longer a problem for me. But I did use this issue to solve a similar one later on and an ordered inner merge solved the issue.

Comment: HI.  If it is no longer an issue, consider mark the correct answer, or post your solution for the problem.  Maybe, you fell that the post needs to be deleted.

Answer (score -1):

You want to merge by index. Therefore you should:

```
merge = df_IfDescr.merge(df_ifOperStatus, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='left')
```

If you want to leave values where 'if' equals 'Desc':

```
merge = merge.reset_index()
merge = merge[merge['if'] == merge['Desc']]
```

This will work only if both columns are of the same type, i.e. both Integer or both Object

Comment: How could I filter the values in "if" column by the values in "Desc" ?

Comment: @Nuclear7740 - I have updated my answer to address your comment

Comment: This worked but only returned a single row.

If I remove the two lines you added I get all the other rows back.

The data does have the desired format now.

Comment: I changed the left_index and right_index to left_on/right_on and the output gave me all the values.

Comment: Yes. After reseting the index you can do that